# Не работает margin-top

Tags: opera, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, css

```
<div class="cont1">
    <div class="cont2">текст</div>
</div>
```

-

```
.cont1 {
    clear: both;
    height: 180px;
    border: 0px solid red;
}
.cont2 {
    margin-top: 100px;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 70px;
    text-align: center;
    border-top: 0px solid black;
}
```

В IE работает, в остальных не работает `margin-top: 100px; у .cont2`, все выравнивается по верхней границе. Если задать для `.cont1 border: 1px solid red;` то все становится ок.

Почему? Как правильно делать?

Comment: вставил ваш код в Chrome. Всё работает. И тут работает: http://jsfiddle.net/H4tQp/

Comment: Почитайте про ["эффект схлопывания"](http://htmlbook.ru/css/margin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того, что бы внутренний блок "отталкивался" от родителя у последнего должен быть задан padding или border хотя бы в 1px. Перенесите

```
margin-top: 100px; из .cont2
```

в

```
padding-top: 100px; .cont1
```

Получится вот так:

```
.cont1 {
    clear: both;
    height: 80px;
    padding-top: 100px;
    border: 0px solid red;
}
.cont2 {
    padding: 5px;
    height: 70px;
    text-align: center;
    border-top: 0px solid black;
}
```